# javascript: conditionally including test files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have inherited a webapp project that is a single html page with JQuery + extra javascript files that are imported into the main app.js. The webapp is intended to be embedded in our main application.

The webapp is distributed through a webpack configuration that builds a bundle.js from all the javascript files and add the html and css file separately due to requirements of the main application.

All this works well, except that, to test the webapp stand-alone, we include testdata in the app.js.

```
import td from ./testdata.js

if ([we are in the main application]) {
   // do whatever necessary to start the webapp
}
else {
  // standalone
  let testdata = td.getTestdata();
  // start webapp
}
```

In the production version I want to prevent the testdata to be bundled with the  bundle.js.

I have tried to import the testdata.js in the else clause, but that resolves in an error.

I have tried to overwrite the testdata.js with an empty one, but that needs to be done in the webpack config and I cannot find where to add a 'pre bundle' action.

What is the best approach to handle this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with webpack, but I found this: https://github.com/caiogondim/webpack-conditional-loader
Maybe it helps you a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an entry point for the webapp and another one for the tests. In this way, you will not need the condicional.

app.js

```
import app from ./bundle.js
// do whatever necessary to start the webapp
```

test.js

```
import app from ./bundle.js
import td from ./testdata.js

let testdata = td.getTestdata();
// app things
```

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier. This sounds like a very elegant approach. This works great. Thank you.